# Entire app with only one AppBar (material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The scenario is simple:

- material-ui with `AppBar`
- `AppBar` differs for each route that I have. For example:

  - /route1: AppBar has iconElementLeft and iconElementRight
  - /route2: AppBar has iconElementLeft
  - /route3: AppBar has iconElementRight
    ...
- I don't want to duplicate code and render `AppBar` in each route
- `children` and `title` also might change

What would be a recommended approach for that?

Although I *might have a solution*, I'm curious to know what others think about this case and why not share their ideas?

Should I use sort of a `Main` container which "listens" to every route change and renders AppBar properties according each route?

I'm gonna give an example so you get the ideia :)

```
renderElementLeft = (location) => {
  if (location is /route1) {
    return <IconButton>...</IconButton>
  }

  if (location is /route2) {
    return <FlatButton label="..." />
  }

  return null // or <div />
}

renderElementRight = (location) => {
  if (location is /route1) {
    return <FlatButton label="..." />
  }

  if (location is /route2) {
    return null // or <div />
  }

  return <IconButton>...</IconButton>
}


const Container = ({ children, location }) => 
  <div>
    <AppBar
      iconElementLeft={renderElementLeft(location)}
      iconElementRight={renderElementRight(location)}
      ...
    />
    {children}
  </div>
```

Give-me your thoughts.

Comment: we achieved the great appbar flexibility with that lib: https://github.com/camwest/react-slot-fill. Each main page now can propogate to appbar slots whatever it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your original idea.

```
    renderElements = (location) => {
    if (location is /route1) {
        return {iconElementLeft:<IconButton>...</IconButton>,
        iconElementRight:<FlatButton label="..." />};
    }

    if (location is /route2) {
        return {iconElementLeft:<FlatButton label="..." />,
        iconElementRight:null};
    }

    return {};
    }


    const Container = ({ children, location }) => 
    <div>
        <AppBar
        {...renderElements(location)}
        />
        {children}
    </div>
```

You could also move the renderElements function to a parent component and pass it down as a prop which when called hands out the necessary props to the AppBar component, leaving your Container ignorant of the location object.